# Можно ли сделать на сайте кнопку "Поделиться" в инстаграмм?

Tags: instagram

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в вопросе: клиент хочет на сайте с рецептами добавить блок "Поделиться рецептом". То есть нажимаем на "Поделиться в вк" - и открывается окно с авторизацией в вк и отправкой ссылки на страницу в ленте или личным сообщением. Есть ли такая возможность для инсты? То есть просто поделиться ссылкой на страницу в директ инсты. Поиск в гугле дает либо статьи о том, как сделать "Поделиться" в самой инсте, либо темы на форумах 2х годичной давности, где пишут, что такой возможности нет(((

Comment: Вот их API. нужно это изучить
https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication https://vk.com/dev/first_guide

Comment: Моего знания английского не хватит, чтобы досконально разобраться в этой документации. Конечно же, это было первое место, куда я полезла искать ответ.

Comment: Мария, привет! Нашли решение?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой возможности в соц сети Instagram нет